# Вывести запись из таблицы MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с памятниками и их описанием, скрипт ниже выводит все имена памятников у виде ссылок, нужно что бы при нажатии на ссылку(имя памятника) выводилось описание памятника которое соответствует имени в БД

```
    $opisanie= $_POST['opisanie'];
    $ima_pamytnika= $_POST['ima_pamytnika'];
    if(isset($_POST["send"])){
    if(empty($_POST["opisanie"]))
    {
     $error[1] = 'введите название фотки<br>';
    }
    if(empty($_POST["ima_pamytnika"]))
    {
     $error[2] = 'введите имя памятника<br>';
    }
    if(!empty($error))
    {
     foreach($error as $value)
     {
      echo 'Ошибка:'.$value;
     }
    }else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pamyatniki(opisanie,name) 
    VALUES ('$opisanie','$ima_pamytnika')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    }

       $res=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM pamyatniki ORDER BY id DESC");
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
       foreach ($r as $k => $d) {
              echo "памятник".' =  <a href="">'.$d."</a><br/>";
       }
    }

// здесь не получается вывести описание
    if(isset($d)){
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT opisanie FROM pamyatniki WHERE name='$ima_pamytnika'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    echo $row['opisanie'];
    }
    }
```

Comment: И где вопрос? Ещё один, не закончивший начальной школы?

Comment: Уважемый Незнайка, Вы ещё и грамоте почти не обучены. Разул глаза, комментарий вижу, вопроса не вижу. А "здесь не получается вывести описание" -- констатация факта, а не вопрос. Причём констатация без уточнений, что не получается, и какие сообщения при этом выводятся.

Comment: уважаемый знайка а как по вашему понимаеться этот косок "нужно что бы при нажатии на ссылку(имя памятника) выводилось описание памятника которое соответствует имени в БД"+// здесь не получается вывести описание
вывод напрашивается сам на себя в самом конце не рабочий код, как бы его организовать для правильной работы которая описана выше, так придельно ясно задан вопрос?

Comment: Абсолютно непонятно. Ваш скрипт для 

      $_POST['opisanie']='opisanie';
      $_POST['ima_pamyatnika']='name';

выводит

      памятник =  <a href="">name</a><br/>

(достаточно бессмысленно, но так написано в скрипте). Что тут не так -- я не понимаю. Результат "придельно" (от слова "приделывать") соответствует коду.

Comment: $_POST['opisanie']='opisanie';
  $_POST['ima_pamyatnika']='name';
такого там нету, там есть такое 
$opisanie= $_POST['opisanie'];
    $ima_pamytnika= $_POST['ima_pamytnika'];

Comment: SELECT opisanie FROM pamyatniki WHERE name='$ima_pamytnika'

А вы выводили этот запрос на экран? А ручками (через копипаст) его выполняли в mysql?

Может быть просто нет того памятника, который вы ищите, потому и не выводит.

И вообще:

    echo "памятник".' =  <a href="">'.$d."</a><br/>";

Это работает? Выводит что-нить? У вас может к Mysql подключиться не может, а мы тут в коде ошибки ищем.

Я в таких случаях комментирую все ветвления и смотрю по какому пути пошло. Дальше погружаюсь ниже и смотрю что не так отрабатывает.

Учитесь отладке - полезно бывает.

Answer (score 0):

Одно могу сказать точно, будет ценным советом вам и всем начинающим PHP специалистам:

Перед тем, как вставлять любые переменные в запрос, их нужно проверять. Иначе, всё может закончиться очень плачевно...

[Интересная и полезная статья на википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Насчёт вот этого:

```
if(isset($d)){
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT opisanie FROM pamyatniki WHERE name='$ima_pamytnika'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo $row['opisanie'];
    }
}
```

Не понимаю, зачем делать while... Ведь `mysql_fetch_array` получает первую строку, удовлетворяющую условиям, а такая строка должна быть одна. Тогда зачем цикл?

Вы уверены, что в вашей таблице есть столбец написание opisanie?

**UPD:**
Можно устроить небольшой debug, для этого можно вписать на видное место

```
echo ("SELECT opisanie FROM pamyatniki WHERE name='$ima_pamytnika'");
```

Проверить, совпадает ли то, что вы видите с тем, что вы должны увидеть. И на всякий случай вставить результат вывода в вашу sql админку (phpmyadmin скорее всего).

Comment: До внедрения sql-кода ещё далеко. Сначала надо, чтобы как-то заработало, а уж потом заборы возводить.

Насчёт while. Одна должна быть строка или не одна -- сиё мне не ведомо. Вдруг не одна? Тогда что?

Answer (score 0):

```
$opisanie= isset($_POST['opisanie']) ? $_POST['opisanie'] : null;
$ima_pamytnika= isset($_POST['ima_pamytnika']) ? $_POST['ima_pamytnika'] : null;
$isSend = isset($_POST["send"]) ? true : false;

echo "1 OPISANIE: " . var_export($opisanie, true) . "<br/>";
echo "2 IMA_PAMYATNIKA: " . var_export($ima_pamytnika, true) . "<br/>";
echo "3 IS_SEND: " . ($isSend ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") . "<br/>";

   if ($isSend) {
    $error = array();
    if (empty($_POST["opisanie"])) {
        $error[] = 'введите название фотки<br>';
    }
    if (empty($_POST["ima_pamytnika"])) {
        $error[] = 'введите имя памятника<br>';
    }
    if (count($error)) {
echo "3_1 HAS ERRORS:<br/>";
        foreach ($error as $value) {
            echo 'Ошибка:'.$value;
        }
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO pamyatniki(opisanie,name) VALUES ('$opisanie','$ima_pamytnika')";
echo "3_2 INSERT SQL: $sql<br/>";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
echo "3_3 INSERT ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "<br/>";
             die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
}

$res=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM pamyatniki ORDER BY id DESC");
echo "4 SELECT FROM PAMYATNIKI:<br/>";
while ($r = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
    foreach ($r as $k => $d) {
        echo "памятник".' =  <a href="">'.$d."</a><br/>";
    }
}

// здесь не получается вывести описание
if (!isset($d)) {
echo "5_0 !ISSET(d)<br/>";
    die("GDE OPISANIE???");
}
$sql = "SELECT opisanie FROM pamyatniki WHERE name='$ima_pamytnika'";
echo "5 SELECT SQL: $sql<br/>";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
echo "6 QUERY RESULTS: " . var_export($query, true) . "<br/>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "7 CURRENT ROW: " . var_export($row, true) . "<br/>";
    echo $row['opisanie'];
}
```

Вставляем это вместо вашего кода и смотрим - что отработалось, а что нет.

Поскольку как-то непонятно на каком месте ломается, то вставил вывод после каждого действия. Смотрите на вывод и говорите что отработало (по выводимым цифрам), что вывело.

У вас может быть таблица пустая.

И еще такой вопрос - а какое описание должно быть выведено? По коду - должно вывестись описание последнего памятника, это правильно?

В общем о результатах сообщите, тогда можно будет сказать что-то точнее.